# Excel web query output control

Tags: macos, excel-web-query, excel-2011

```
Excel for Mac 2011
Version 14.2.4 (120824)
Mac OS X 10.6.8
```

This web query file

```
WEB
1
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=SGOL&f=sn
```

Returns this text into a spreadsheet cell.

```
SGOL,"ETFS Physical Swi"
```

What I would like to know is how to get the returned data to automagically be converted to columns, using the "," as delimiter?